# Borrar cookies al cerrar el navegador (Resuelto)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, popup

quisiera saber si hay alguna forma con (JS, jQuery o con PHP) de al cerrar el navegador borrar la cookie.
Pongo contexto: estoy haciendo un pop up y quiero que cuando cargue por primera vez la página este me aparezca pero si la gente le da al (cerrar) que este desaparezca aunque recargue la página. Todo hasta ahí lo tengo bien hecho.

El problema viene cuando quiero que vuelva a salir después de cerrar el navegador (guarda la cookie que he creado) y no me sale el pop up.

Dejo el código que tengo:

```
<script>
  var popupName = "popupv1";

  jQuery(function($) {
    console.log("Javascript popup");

    console.log("Cargando pagina");
    // Handler for .ready() called.



    function openPopUp() {
      var popup = getCookie(popupName);
      if (popup != 1) {
        $("#cd_footer_chat").css("display", "block");

        $("#open_cd_footer_chat_1").click(function() {
          $("#cd_footer_chat").css("display", "none");
          $("#cd_footer_chat_1").css("display", "block");
        });
        $("#open_cd_footer_chat_2").click(function() {
          $("#cd_footer_chat_1").css("display", "none");
          $("#cd_footer_chat_2").css("display", "block");
        });
        $(".cd_chat_close").click(function() {
          $("#cd_footer_chat").css("display", "none");
          $("#cd_footer_chat_1").css("display", "none");
          $("#cd_footer_chat_2").css("display", "none");
          removePopUp();
        });
        $(".popup-close").click(function() {
          $("#cd_footer_chat").css("display", "none");
          $("#cd_footer_chat_1").css("display", "none");
          $("#cd_footer_chat_2").css("display", "none");
          removePopUp();
        });

      }
    }

    function removePopUp() {
      setCookie(popupName, "1", 10);
    }

    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
      const d = new Date();
      d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      let expires = "expires=" + 0;
      document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
      let name = cname + "=";
      let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
      let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
      for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        let c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
          c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
          return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
      }
      return "";
    }
    openPopUp();

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Para que la cookie permanezca activa hasta que se cierre el navegador, especifica el tiempo de expiración en cero.

Comment: Okey, gracias voy a probarlo

Comment: Perfecto muchisimas gracias, ha funcionado perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a Triby he encontrado la solución:
tenía que cambiar el dato de expires a 0

```
  let expires = "expires=" + 0;
```

En la función de setCookies()

Lo dejo corregido por si ha alguien le interesa